# ActionScript3:Undefined property error

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm making a toggle button to resume/pause the audio in Adobe flash CS 5:
I used a Code Snippet "click to play/stop Sound".

Here is the code:

```
pause_play_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2);
    var fl_ToPlay_2:Boolean = true;
    var resumeTime:Number = 0.00;
    var s:Sound = new Tanishma_Sound();
    var fl_SC_2:SoundChannel ;

    function fl_ClickToPlayStopSound_2(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {

    if(fl_ToPlay_2)
    {
        f1_SC_2 = s.play (resumeTime);
    }
    else
    {
        resumeTime = f1_SC_2.position;
        f1_SC_2.stop ();
    }
    fl_ToPlay_2 = !fl_ToPlay_2;
}
```

I have this error and I don't know how to fix it:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 47 1120: Access of undefined property f1_SC_2.

Any Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that Flash can't find something you've referenced.  In your case, this is because of a syntax typo.

You have defined: (note the f then the letter l)

```
var fl_SC_2:SoundChannel;
```

Yet later on, you've change the 'l' to the numeral '1' in three places.

```
f1_SC_2
```

Should be:

```
if(fl_ToPlay_2)
{
    fl_SC_2 = s.play (resumeTime);
}
else
{
    resumeTime = fl_SC_2.position;
    fl_SC_2.stop ();
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I didn't see that was l not 1 :)

Comment: They do look very very very similar in most fonts used for coding.  I'm actually surprised I even noticed.